# Strante interpretation of unit expression in grid

Tags: r, graphics, grid, units-of-measurement

I am making a graphic using grid, and want to draw some text. I ran into an issue when specifying the coordinates of the text.

Specifically, I found out that I can use both a straight unit, such as `unit(1, "native")` and an expression that evaluates to a unit, such as `unit(1, "native") + unit(1, "mm")`. But as soon as I have two native units in the expression, the text is plotted not where I expect it, but in a position which might be using npc units.

In the following MWE, I would expect "3" to be printed to the right of the middle (0 in native units), but it is printed far to the left.

```
 require(grid)

grid.newpage()
vp.data.region <- viewport(x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.5, "npc"), width = unit(0.8, "npc"), height = unit(0.8, "npc"), xscale=c(-1,1), yscale=c(-1,1), name = "data region")
pushViewport(vp.data.region)
grid.xaxis()
grid.yaxis()

grid.text("1", unit(0, "native"),unit(0, "native")) #places the text where it should be
grid.text("2", unit(0, "native") + unit(10, "mm"), unit(0, "native")) # it is possible to use an expression adding mixed units 
grid.text("3", unit(0.6, "native") - unit(0.5, "native") + unit(1, "mm") , unit(0, "native")) # suddenly, it looks like the unit expression is being interpreted as npc?
```

[image]

What causes this problem, and how can I avoid it? Note that it would be very difficult to specify the unit with a single expression, because I start with a point already specified as native units plus some millimeters, and have to position the text a certain distance from it, which I have to again calculate using both native units and millimeters.

Comment: Perhaps this question might be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045990/convert-units-from-npc-to-native-using-grid-in-r. I'm not sure exactly what problem you are trying to solve so I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: @MrFlick When you look at my MWE, I am trying to print the text "3" at the coordinates of x=0.1native, y=0native. Instead, it gets printed somewhere else on the screen. Thank you for linking the other question, I can't see yet how I could use it, since I don't want to use npc units.

Comment: Oh, so your real question is more like why doesn’t `unit(.6, “native”) - unit(.5, “native”)` equal `unit(.1, “native”)`?

Comment: @MrFlick yes, it was my expectation that it would equal it. When I do a naive arithmetic calculation in my head, that's the result I get, and since I'm new to grid, I have no idea why the naive calculation doesn't apply. And also, the question is, how do I get the coordinates of `unit(.1, "native")` when I only have the information that I want to go 0.5 native units to the left of `unit(0.6, "native")`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the primary units for the calculation are the `npc` units. When addition/subtraction occurs, each value is convert to `npc` units. We can use the `convertX` function to see how these values pan out. When you use native units, those values are mapped to `npc` units via the `xscale=` values. Note that

```
convertX(unit(0.6, "native"), "npc")
# [1] 0.8npc
convertX(unit(0.5, "native"), "npc")
# [1] 0.75npc
convertX(unit(0.6, "native") - unit(0.5, "native"), "npc")
# [1] 0.0499999999999999npc
```

compared to

```
convertX(unit(0.1, "native"), "npc")
# [1] 0.55npc
```

You can't do atritmetic in native space using `npc` coordinates. If you need to calculate 0.5 native units to the left of 0.6, then you need to do that arithmatic in native space

```
convertX(unit(0.6 - 0.5, "native"), "npc")
# [1] 0.55npc
```

If for some reason you can't do that, then you can make a function that takes a unit and a shift and does the arithmetic on that scale. For example

```
nativeShift <- function(unit, shift) {
  stopifnot(class(unit)=="unit")
  stopifnot(attr(unit, "unit")=="native")
  stopifnot(is.numeric(shift))
  unit(unclass(unit) + shift, "native")
}

convertX(nativeShift(unit(.6, "native"), -.5), "npc")
# [1] 0.55npc
```

With your plotting example that would look like

```
grid.text("3", nativeShift(unit(0.6, "native"), -0.5) + unit(1, "mm") , unit(0, "native"))
```