# How does The Economist make these lines near the title using using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I really like the aesthetics of The Economist magazine and I use the theme_economist often. However, I am curious as to how they create the red lines in the top left in a lot of their charts. See image below and where I circled.

[image]

Comment: does the red line have a meaning? (This doesn't help with your question, but I'm curious)

Comment: no I just thinks it looks nice and professional

Comment: It would help if you could provide a simple reproducible example of a graph to which you'd like to add the red line. Also, I don't see anything circled in the image you provided.

Comment: yeah sorry forgot to add that piece, I am just talking about that red line on the top left of the chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a mix of "how to annotate outside the plot area" and "how to annotate in npc coordinates". Therefore, I offer two options.

Both unfortunately require a bit of trial and error in order to correctly place the segment. For option 1, it is the y coordinate which we have to "guess", and for option 2 it's x!

In order to make y slightly less guess work, I tried an approach to position is relative to the default axis breaks. [using the fabulous information from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41454471/7941188). This is of course not necessary, one can also simply trial and error.

For option 2, I modified a function [from user Allan Cameron's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63742203/7941188). He mentions a way to figure out x and y, I guess one could use the title, and then place the annotation based on that.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <-
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("lorem ipsum") +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(t = 1.5, unit = "lines")) # this is always necessary

# OPTION 1
# semi-programmatic approach to figure out y coordinates
y_defaultticks <- with(mtcars, labeling::extended(range(wt)[1], range(wt)[2], m = 5))
y_default <- y_defaultticks[2] - y_defaultticks[1] 
y_seg <- max(mtcars$wt) + 0.75 * y_default

p +
annotate(geom = "segment", x = - Inf, xend = 12, y = y_seg, yend = y_seg, 
         color = "red", size = 5) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off", ylim = c(NA, max(mtcars$wt)),
                  xlim = c(min(mtcars$mpg), NA))
```

[image]

```r
# OPTION 2
annotate_npc <- function(x, y, height, width, ...) {
  grid::grid.draw(grid::rectGrob(
    x = unit(x, "npc"), y = unit(y, "npc"), height = unit(height, "npc"), width = unit(width, "npc"),
    gp = grid::gpar(...)
  ))
}

p
annotate_npc(x = 0.07, y = 1, height = 0.05, width = 0.05, fill = "red", col = NA)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>