# Arrow location based on arrow size in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to draw an arrow with its location based on the dimensions of the arrow. Here is a reprex with the desired result:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggarchery)

line <- structure(list(structure(c(0, 15, 35, 50, 60, 80, 100, 120, 15, 
                                   18, 25, 30, 45, 55, 57, 57, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                                 dim = c(8L, 3L), class = c("XYZ", "LINESTRING", "sfg"))), 
                  class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", "sfc"), precision = 0, 
                  bbox = structure(c(xmin = 0, ymin = 15, xmax = 120, ymax = 57), class = "bbox"), 
                  z_range = structure(c(zmin = 0, zmax = 0), class = "z_range"), 
                  crs = structure(list(input = NA_character_, wkt = NA_character_), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)

lim_arrow <- structure(list(x = c(2.4, 14.4, 110.4, 117.6), 
                            y = c(15.48, 17.88, 57, 57), 
                            x1 = c(2.35, 14.35, 110.45, 117.65), 
                            type = c("start", "end", "start", "end")), 
                       class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

y_inc <- 1

p <- ggplot()+geom_sf(data=line)+
  geom_arrowsegment(data = lim_arrow, 
                    aes(x = x1, xend = x, y = y+y_inc, yend = y+y_inc, fill=type, col=type), 
                    arrow_positions = c(0.25, 1), 
                    arrows = list(arrow(length = unit(0.025, "npc"), angle = 90), 
                                  arrow(length = unit(0.025, "npc"), type = 'closed'))
                    )+labs(x="", y="")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

[image]

I am using the [geom_arrowsegment](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggarchery/man/geom_arrowsegment.html) function of the ggarchery package to create two arrows in approximately the same position. One of the arrows was changed to a line. The y_inc value was set manually, but I want to calculate this value automatically, so the vertical line is on the line plotted. The y_inc value should be based on the size of the arrow (the arrow created as a vertical line).

I tried to use the **convert** function from the grid package, but didn't get the results I wanted. I also checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045990/convert-units-from-npc-to-native-using-grid-in-r), but didn't have success.

Any ideas?